# Angular: Change the checked status of Checked Box based on Radio button Value Change

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to check all the checked box based on the value of the radio button and vice verse on Unchecked Radio Button Click. I am trying to achieve it in the following way. But I am not able to do so.

**Component Html**

```
   <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="sel" value="0" [(ngModel)]="clientSelectionType">Select All 
    </label>

      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="sel" value="1" [(ngModel)]="clientSelectionType">Unselect All
    </label>

<div class="form-group">
    <h3> radio button </h3>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="clientSelectionType===0"> Test 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="clientSelectionType===0"> Test 2
    </label>
     <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="clientSelectionType===0"> Test 4
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="clientSelectionType===0"> Test 3
    </label>
</div>
```

StackBlitzLink: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ffuhsz.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `string` vs `number` comparison. You are doing `clientSelectionType === 0`, which is `'0' === 0`. The reason it's a string is because you are binding the value like this: `value="1"` on the radio. This results in a string value. Try using the binding brackets for the value:

```
<input type="radio" name="sel" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="clientSelectionType">
```